# Select a record that needs to satisfy two conditions but they are actually two records in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

consider this situation:
Table:

```
Code    Lang
123 En
123 De
345 De
```

Consider this table where a code has two different lang EN and DE.
I want to show records from this table where a code has only 'DE' but not 'EN'
How to achieve this ?

Comment: please tag one database engine

Comment: db is not necessary for this question. This question can be solved with ansi-sql commands with my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `except` or `minus` depending upon the database being used.

```
select code from table
where lang = 'DE'
except --in sql server --minus in oracle
select code from table
where lang <> 'DE'
```

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server, there are multiple ways you could approach this, though for most engines (including sql server) a simple self-join will work across the board:

```
select t.code, t.lang
from   table t
left join table t2
on     t.code = t2.code
and    t2.lang != 'De'
where  t.lang = 'De'
and    t2.code is null;
```

Other approaches (depending on the database engine) could include a NOT EXISTS subquery in the where clause, an EXCEPT operator (as @vkp answered), a NOT IN clause/subquery in the where clause, an OUTER APPLY (in sql server), etc.

If you narrow down the db engine for us, might be able to give a more targeted answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
create table #test(
code int, lang varchar(2))
insert #test select 123, 'En'
insert #test select 123, 'De'
insert #test select 345, 'De'

   select code from #test t1
    where exists (select * from #test t2 
                   where t1.code = t2.code 
                     and t1.lang = t2.lang 
                     and t2.lang = 'De')
    and not exists (select * from #test t3 
                     where t1.code = t3.code 
                      -- and t1.lang = t3.lang  this is trick part
                       and t3.lang = 'En')
```

Result:

```
code        lang 
----------- ---- 
        345 De
```

Comment: Can actually simplify this (and in most engines get a more efficient plan/execution) to just:

select * from #test t2 
where t2.lang = 'De'
and not exists (select * from #test t3 
                where t2.code = t3.code 
                and t3.lang = 'En');

Comment: this would be better.

Answer (score -1):

If there is a set list of Languages you don't want to show,

```
Select Code, Lang
Where Lang <> 'DE'
```

Comment: Assuming that to match the question your clause would be Lang <> 'EN', this would even still include records that may have both 'DE' and 'EN', as you're simply excluding a certain set of values.  The question was "show records where a code has ONLY 'DE' but not 'EN', which is a slightly different issue than just filtering out certain records.  This would work fine if it were used as a NOT EXISTS or NOT IN type subquery along with a larger statement, but certainly not stand-alone as is.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was in between thoughts this morning when I answered this, and misread the question. I would delete my answer, but your comment adds value to this discussion.